# Create a Facebook App that can post to a page I am an admin of

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As part of the website I am working on, I need to be able to post directly to the wall of my clients Facebook Page.

I have created an App and am successfully posting to my own dummy profile by simply using:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
    'link' => 'my_url',
        'message' => 'my_message'
     );
```

Now I need to modify this to post to my clients page, im assuming I cant just change 'me' to by their page ID because that would be a massive security flaw so I need to get permission somehow to post to their page. I am an admin for the page, how can I do this? Or do I actually need to be logged in with the user account that created the page?

I have looked all around in the developer section at creating an app but there doesn't seem to be any way of creating an app for a different account.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on this.
Many thanks

Comment: Login as you and then get a page access token which is described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to post to a Facebook page, you need to go through a two steps process -

- login as the user using the extended user token,
- get the user's token for the page
- post to the page using the page's token.

The following code should be able to post a  message to your page. **I HAVEN'T DEBUGGED IT** since it is simplified from my own web site :-) Don't forget to include the Facebook SDK files:

```
function extract_access_token_of_facebook_page_by_id($array_of_all_user_pages,$page_id){
    $num_of_pages=count($array_of_all_user_pages['data']);
    $the_page_token="";

    for ($i=0; $i<$num_of_pages; $i++){
        if ($array_of_all_user_pages['data'][$i]['id']==$page_id){
            $the_page_token=$array_of_all_user_pages['data'][$i]['access_token'];
            }
        }
    return $the_page_token;
    }

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'     => $YOUR-APP-ID,
            'secret'    => $YOUR-APP-SECRET,
            ));

try
    {
    $facebook->setAccessToken($THE-USER-TOKEN);
    $page_id = YOUR-PAGE-ID;
    $fanpage_access_token=extract_access_token_of_facebook_page_by_id($facebook->api("/me/accounts"),$page_id);
    $args = array();
    $args['access_token'] = $fanpage_access_token;
    $args['message'] = "THE TEXT YOU WANT TO POST";
    $api_url="/".$page_id."/feed";
    $api_response = $facebook->api($api_url, 'post', $args);
    }
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
echo 'Error facebookservice'.$e;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much PalDev!! This did the trick!! Tiny bit fo tweaking because some elements where objects rather than arrays in the extract_access_token_of_facebook_page_by_id method but pretty much bang on!! Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Please look into Application developer section. It will help you. Create on developer account and you will be able to access page.

[image: Facebook Developer Section]

Answer (score 0):

you code is for old sdk version i think, it not work for me : Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found